# Does anyone see any problem in this program

Tags: posix, systems-programming

After not getting an answer I liked for [this question about chroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737008/how-run-in-a-chroot-jail-not-as-root-and-without-sudo), I went and rolled my own solution:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {
  char* path = "/";
  char* name = "nobody";
  char* exe = "/bin/false";
  struct passwd *pass;

  if(argc < 4) { printf("Need more args: username chroot exe args...\n"); return 1; }
  name = argv[1];
  path = argv[2];
  exe = argv[3];

  if(!(pass = getpwnam(name))) { printf("Unknown user %s", name); return 2; }

  if(chroot(path)) {
    if(errno == EPERM) { printf("chroot not allowed\n"); return 3; }
    printf("chroot failed\n");
    return 4;
  }
  chdir("/");

  if(setgid(pass->pw_gid)) { printf("setgid failed: %d\n", pass->pw_gid); return 5; }
  if(setuid(pass->pw_uid)) { printf("setuid failed: %d\n", pass->pw_uid); return 6; }

  environ = envp;
  execvp(exe, argv + 3);

  printf("exec of %s failed\n", exe);
  return 7;
}
```

Does anyone see any bugs in that (or even better, know of a tool that makes it redundant)?

Answer (score 4):

1. Why do you assign defaults to `path`, `name`, `exe`, if you overwrite them anyway?
2. You should not return negative values from within `main()`. It makes the actual return value unclear, as POSIX uses only the 8 least significant bits of it (i.e. `-1` is returned as `255`, etc.).
3. You shouldn't rely on `getuid()`; `chroot()` would work `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability too. Instead, you could try to `chroot()` and check if `errno == EPERM`.
4. `chroot()` doesn't change the current working directory; I think you should call `chdir()` too.
5. What does `environ = envp` assignment exactly do? It seems hacky.
6. In any case, you could add better error reporting.

And finally, [chrootuid](http://ftp.porcupine.org/pub/security/index.html#software) is probably the tool you were looking for.

Comment: 1) sane defaults avoid a whole class of bugs. 5) `environ` is used by `execvp` and I don't remember if it's set by default. 6) :b

Comment: As for chrootuid, it's not a standard tool and assumes that I want to use syslog (and I don't, so I can't use it as-is). Given that I was looking to get away from a) having to install something and b) writing my own, it has no advantage to me.

Comment: environ is set by default, AFAIK it is POSIX equivalent of envp. Thus, you're mixing two coding standards. And I don't think you could be able to find anything better. Especially that you want to acquire the UID/GID before entering chroot.