# does chroot() require root privileges?

Tags: c, linux, root, chroot

When I try to use chroot with "." or the complete pathname as argument, perror tells me "Operation not permitted".

If the answer to my question is yes, is there another way to change root directory ? (Without barbarian methods using strcmp() / strncmp())

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737008/how-to-run-a-command-in-a-chroot-jail-not-as-root-and-without-sudo

Answer (score 10):

`chroot` can only be used by `root` him/her/itself. And no, there won't be any other way without compromising security.

From Wikipedia

> Only the root user can perform a chroot. This is intended to prevent users from putting a setuid program inside a specially crafted chroot jail (for example, with a fake /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow file) that would fool it into a privilege escalation.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) for the article.

Answer (score 5):

You could try `fakechroot chroot`

Answer (score 4):

Try a tool called **PRoot**
It's based on ptrace and syscall instrumentation and one of possible usecases is to achieve something like chroot.

Answer (score 0):

From user space, you can use the schroot command. Add a few lines to /etc/schroot/schroot.conf

```
[xenial]
description=Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)
type=directory
directory=/srv/chroots/xenial
aliases=xenial-lts
profile=minimal
users=bob
personality=linux64
```

Then from your user account:

```
schroot -c xenial
```